# When does IIS log a request?

Tags: iis, proxy, logging

This sounds silly, but when do they log requests? I have a web application, and about 500 HTTP proxies that will load up that application. But problem is sometimes (and this morning a lot), the proxy (using php sockets) believes it connected and the response that came back was blank.

BUT IIS has no log of this request.

When does IIS log a request? Could it be rejecting the connection, and not even processing the request?

Answer (score 6):

IIS logs requests after they have completed.  W3WP.exe logs to memory after the response has been sent to the client.  Then, at regular intervals (usually less than 10 seconds) W3Wp.exe writes to the IIS log file specified in the Website configuration.  You may have to wait several seconds before requests are visible in the IIS log file.  I believe that HTTP.sys is written to in realtime.  If you don't see your requests in the IIS log file, check that you are indeed visiting the website you think you are.  You can also check the most recent \%systemroot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR log file for your request... if IIS can't handle your request, HTTP.sys will log why IIS could not accept the request.  Hope this helps.
-Chris

Comment: Do you have any sources for your claim that requests are logged after they've completed? I'm not disputing the claim so much as curious about the context or background about this behavior.

Comment: Kenny, the log includes the time taken to execute the request... therefore, the request must be complete before that information is available for logging.

Comment: That helped me, we could not find request in IIS logs, but we found canceled request their. Thx a lot.